# Control constraint in storyboard

Tags: xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have two controls in the storyboard, named `xLabel` and `yLabel`

`yLabel` can be anywhere on screen.
`xLabel` is 50 above `yLabel`, and right aligned with the `yLabel`

In other word, x and y position of `xLabel` is dependence on `yLabel`. How can i set the constraint in `xLabel`? Is it possible to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> yLabel can be any where on screen

No, it can't. You must supply constraints that position it unambiguously.

> xLabel is 50 above yLabel, and right align with the yLabel. Is it possible to do this?

Certainly. Pin the bottom of xLabel to the top of yLabel with a `constant` of 50, and pin the right edge of xLabel to the right edge of yLabel with a `constant` of 0.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Xcode. @matt, How to pin the bottom of xLabel to the top of yLabel?

Comment: "Pin" means use a constraint.